# Missing ":" using Algolia Instant Search

Tags: algolia, instantsearch

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

I'm seeing this error in my console using Algolia Instant Search on Firefox (Mac). It has been reported to me that IE11 is visually displaying the same, however, I'm not sure of the error in IE? Both Chrome and Safari are error free.

When I decompile my code, Firefox points to this line as being the culprit, however, I'm not sure that this is the problem line?

```
const {container, placeholder, delayTime = 500, suggestionsIndex, mainIndex} = renderParams.widgetParams;
```

=====

Update

The issue is with the way the delayTime is set although I'm not 100% sure how it should be set. In the short term, I'm not setting delayTime the way it's set above. Instead, I've commented out delayTime, and I'm replacing the places it is called with 500.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the example provided by the InstantSearch documentation uses some syntax that might not be available in the JavaScript version shipped with your browser.

```
const {container, placeholder, delayTime = 500, suggestionsIndex, mainIndex} = renderParams.widgetParams;
```

is equivalent to (in modern browsers):

```
const container = renderParams.widgetParams.container;
const placeholder = renderParams.widgetParams.placeholder;
const delayTime = renderParams.widgetParams.delayTime || 500;
const suggestionsIndex = renderParams.widgetParams.suggestionsIndex;
const mainIndex = renderParams.widgetParams.mainIndex;
```

A common solution to fix those browser-discrepancies issues is to transpile your JavaScript code to the lowest-common-denominator of currently available JavaScript version using [Babeljs](https://babeljs.io/). The learning curve of Babel can be steep at first, but this has become a invaluable tool to ship code that works on all browsers.